# View outside View Folder Does not Use _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to keep all the code for each ASP.NET Controller in it's own folder, contrary to the out-of-the-box setup.  So for example my `Home` folder will have the `HomeController`, all the ViewModels for each view, and all the Views related to `Home`.

The problem is if i move my view to the `Home` folder, and hit it like:

```
return View("~/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

It does not use my `_ViewStart`, `_Layout`, or `_ViewImports` pages in the `Views` folder.  I'd like to be able to move those anywhere in my application and still have a way for all views to be able to reference them.  Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: You probably need a custom view engine to tell it where to look for views, layouts etc.

Comment: In your cshtml file, try specify the layout to force using the particular layout `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml"` (NB: you need to specify where the actual layout file is though)

Comment: Or I recommend looking at the feature folders package by K. Scott Allen which is explicitly for doing this exact thing https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders

Comment: Holy moly @DavidG this is exactly what I was after.  I've watched a lot of K. Scott Allen's pluralsight videos but had not seen this package before.  What a cool dude.  Thanks again.

Comment: The problem with having a good idea is that someone else has probably already had it! I think I saw him talking about this in an NDC video.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use something like feature folders, which I describe in this MSDN article (there is also a related Nuget package in addition to Scott Allen's):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx

If you can wait for Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core 2.0, they offer many of the same benefits of feature folders. I have a forthcoming MSDN article on the topic, but you can see an example that builds on the above article's sample in this GitHub branch (which will most likely be merged into master once the article is published):
https://github.com/ardalis/organizingaspnetcore/tree/ardalis/razorpages